# How to execute junit test case sequentially

Tags: spring, junit, integration-testing

I am writing integration test case which is used to create and update a data

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class, webEnvironment = 
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class MyIntegrationTest {

private String baseUrl="http://192.168.6.177/api/v1/";
@Autowired
TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
Long createdId;        // trying to set ID which is coming after test1_AddData

@Test
public void test1_AddData() throws Exception {
    ABC abc = new ABC("Name");
    HttpEntity<ABC> requestBodyData = new HttpEntity<>(ABC);
    ParameterizedTypeReference<RestTemplateResponseEnvelope<ABC>> typeReference =
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<RestTemplateResponseEnvelope<ABC>>() {
            };

    ResponseEntity<RestTemplateResponseEnvelope<ABC>> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            baseUrl + "/presenceType",
            HttpMethod.POST, requestBodyData, typeReference);

    Assert.assertTrue(HttpStatus.CREATED.equals(response.getStatusCode()));
    createdId = response.getBody().getData().getId();
}


@Test
public void test2_updateData() throws Exception {


    ABC abc = new ABC("NEW NAME");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------" + createdId);    /// it is giving null 
    HttpEntity<ABC> requestBodyData = new HttpEntity<>(ABC);
    ResponseEntity<ABC> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            baseUrl + "/presenceType/" + createdId,
            HttpMethod.PUT, requestBodyData, ABC.class);
    Assert.assertTrue(HttpStatus.OK.equals(response.getStatusCode()));
    createdId = response.getBody().getId();
}

 }
```

the output of my execution 
------------------------------------------null

What needs to be done to make this execution i.e calling of second function after the exection of first.
NOTE : The code also contains delete method which needs to be called after third.

Comment: Change `Long createdId;` to `static Long createdId;`. JUnit will throw everything else away between tests.

Answer (score 3):

FixMethodOrder not working for me, so I find another way to do this.

We can use **@TestMethodOrder** from Junit jupiter

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.5.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestMethodOrder.html

@Order annotation used to specify the sequence

**Example code:**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;

@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class DummyTest1 {
    
        @Test
        @Order(2)
        public void read(){
            System.out.println("read");
        }
    
        @Test
        @Order(4)
        public void delete(){
            System.out.println("delete");
        }
    
        @Test
        @Order(1)
        public void create(){
            System.out.println("create");
        }
    
        @Test
        @Order(3)
        public void update(){
            System.out.println("update");
        }
 }
```

It will execute in sequence order order1, order2, order3, order4

So testing order will be,

- create
- read
- update
- delete

Comment: For those wanting to run tests in the order the methods are defined, I wasn't able to find a way, but the next closest thing was to use `MethodOrderer.MethodName.class` and name my tests like `test1_something()`, `test2_somethingElse()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not good practice to fix order in Tests. But If you are using JUnit above version 4.11, it has annotation @FixMethodOrder.

You can set order by method names.

Example:

```
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class OrderTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("test1");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("test2");
    }
}
```

For further reading @[FixMethodOder](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/FixMethodOrder.html)

Junit Git Page: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/test-execution-order

Custom Implemenation: https://memorynotfound.com/run-junit-tests-method-order/